# Enabling NAT loopback on HG556a router?

Tags: networking, router, nat

This is one of the standard issue vodafone routers. So i set up web-server on my laptop, and it is accessible to the internet now.

However I need to be able to access it from my machine using the public address. But I just cannot find where to enable nat loopback. I looked for options in both regular and advanced user logins (web interfaces). So I suppose the last option is telneting into it, and using commands to do it.. but I don't know how to access it (cant find the credentials).

http://rhiggins.sdf-eu.org/blog/index.php?entry=entry110722-164625

In above link it says that i can find this info in configuration file, but anyone could tell me how to access it?

And then what commands should I use to enable the NAT loopback?

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be supported. I have gotten around this in the past by ssh tunneling through a local socks proxy or by using one of the many free proxies available online.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Scandalist, it may or may not be supported on your router. However, if it is, [try the commands recommended here](http://diary.piku.org.uk/2009/04/17/port-forwarding-and-nat-loopback-on-a-zyxel-adsl-router/). My router was different than the one listed there but the commands worked the same.

First, telnet into the router (most platforms will have this available in CLI) It may require a user/pass which should be the same as your web interface credentials:

```
telnet <router ip>
```

Then enable loopback:

```
ip nat loopback on
```

Then exit telnet:

```
exit
```

Some routers allow you save the setting. I tried doing this on my router using some commands that it displayed in its "help" but couldn't get it to work.

I ended up adding the telnet stuff into a script on another machine with a cron job every 5 minutes, this way if the router is ever loses power I will telnet back into it after it comes back up and re-enable the loopback. The script is a one liner:

```
(echo <password>; echo "ip nat loopback on"; sleep 1; echo "exit" ) | telnet <router_ip> <username>
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, but did not work. I am starting to suspect that as Scandalist said already it is simply not supported :)